# Плагин для поиска в выпадающем списке

Tags: css3, jquery, css, плагин

Подскажите, пожалуйста, плагин для поиска в выпадающем списке.
Т.е. есть инпут поле, по клику на которое ниже появляется выпадающий список с вариантами выбора. При вводе текста в этот инпут список автоматический фильтруется.

Comment: @Vasile, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, будет проще использовать jQuery Autocomplete.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Answer (score 0):

[Awesomplete](http://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/).

Либо [смотрите результат поиска](http://goo.gl/fO3frx) на github.